# Make a php float to 2 decimal places

Tags: php, floating-point, decimal, number-formatting, decimalformat

I have a float that outputs as

float 1.5

I need to output as

float 1.50 or as a decimal, this give me a string.

```
 $delivery_cost = number_format((float)$deliveryCharge, 2);
```

Comment: what's the problem? you're doing output, which means you're displaying strings. you should keep data in their native format until it comes time to display them, and then create a formatted COPY for output.

Comment: I need to send it as a decimal not as a string and with the 2 decimal placed to an api.

Comment: unless that api's taking in a binary format, you're probably building xlm or json or whatever, which are all TEXT.